# Minimum Spanning Tree on D Wave Processor

Tags: d-wave, annealing

I am attempting to implement a minimum spanning tree problem on the D wave quantum computing architecture. I have seen many graph problems implemented, such as a graph coloring example. There are also a variety of Traveling Salesman Tutorials available. What would be the best approach for making a functioning application of the MST on a D Wave system? Are there any related tutorials or examples to this problem other than the ones mentioned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well first you will have to specify the MST in a QUBO/Ising formulation. [In this article showing formulations for different types of problems](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1302.5843.pdf), section 8.1 is about the MST with a maximal degree constraint. [This paper](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1742-6596/681/1/012005/pdf) contains results of Spanning Tree calculations.

When you have the formulation, you map it on the Chimera Graph if the hardware size is not limiting. Otherwise, one would try a divide and conquer approach to solve the optimization problem.